# MVVM in wpf , how to add ObservebleObject to model from service reference

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I got a WPF client application that connected to a wcf service reference.

My models are from the service reference only.

I want to create a viewmodel for each model, how can i add NotifyPropertyChangedEvent without adding each property manually from the model to the viewmodel

I saw in mvvm light , that the model can ineherit from ObservebleObject, only problem is that the model is created else where and i'm just getting the reference.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is must to put the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Model`. You can simply implement it in `ViewModel`.

Why your `View` needs to tell the `Model` (via `ViewModel`) that something has been changed ? I think it should only tell `ViewModel` that there has been a change. Then let `View Model` play with `Model`.

Comment: Yeah, i thought so too, but that means that i need to create a property in the viewmodel for each one of the properties in the model.. no ?

Comment: No, you only need to create those properties which you want to show in View

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer i will do it on the view model

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call a method on your service, it's going to return a new DTO. It will never give you the same instance back, and you can't use a service to manipulate one object instance - all data used in communication is transient.

So those instances can never be updated (they're not models) so implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be pointless. Instead you need to write a view model and copy your DTOs into that. The view model is where you would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I fully agree with Tim. I find it very confusing that the svcutil-created data classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged, although their properties usually never change.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer i will do it on the view model